# Jquery conflict with others

Tags: html, conflict, smoothing

ok so I use a lot of different things to do the web, I use bootstrap carousel first and it works fine but then I use smooth scrolling from [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) then the arrow of carousel do the navigate to section instead of sliding to next element.

I write filter tab by jquery to display my pics then I apply fancybox2, after zooming my pic dissapeared

even jquery I write by myself conflicts with others, what should I do if it happens? find another plugins? do u prefer to use framework and plugin a lot or try to do everything on your own when working in real environment?

Im a beginner please  forgive me if the questions are stupid.

Comment: you should add some code and double check your English since it is not very clear what you are asking

Comment: I mean my web has many conflictions when using jquery framework, but what I want to ask is people's opinion what do they prefer to do in that situation? do u even read?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you wrote. I guess its multiple-jquery file your having on the same page.. Double check project for duplicacy and remove them and better point to one single source